# Create Custom Column with IF and lookup functionality to own table

Tags: powerbi, lookup, powerquery

I have merged two tabels ( sales and forecast ). For all the rows coming from sales query the *cost price* column has a value. The forecast rows **does not** have that.

In order to calculate future metrics/KPI I need to make a Power Query transformation that populates *cost price* on all forecast rows. I would like to do some kind of refence to the *ProductName* (exits both on the sales and forecast rows) and pull the *cost price* from the sales rows. The *ProductName* can have multiple entries in the table, but will be the same for alle the rows. So maybe a find first/max or something would be fine.

However, I am not sure have to make this calcuated column with some sort of lookup to ProductName?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you can definitely do so

Here is an [excellent Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) form Microsoft on LookupValue

In addition check this [Thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Lookupvalue-multiple-conditions-greater-lesser-than-date/td-p/467426) as well. It will give you more Idea.

I would do something like

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(Product[SafetyStockLevel], [ProductName], " Mountain-400-W Silver, 46")
```